# Listing Authors - URL Formats

Tags: url-rewriting, author

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I amend the fixed “author” part in the URL?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44430/how-do-i-amend-the-fixed-author-part-in-the-url)

Hullo,

I'm needing to have custom URLs for authors so for example mysite.com/team/johndoe would be the eventual URL. This should list that particular user, but I was hoping to use the author.php template to do so.

The following gives further details, but it doesn't really clarify whether this is possible as it's not designed to: http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

Is there any fancy way of doing URL rewriting for this case?

Comment: Why does the default http://site.com/author/johndoe/ not work for your situation?

Comment: A client requirement, basically!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-htaccess-control/. It has support for rewriting author urls. Should be a quick and easy fix.