# How do I amend the fixed "author" part in the URL?

Tags: urls, localization

I am creating a localized instance of WordPress and one can easily configure the category and tag parts of the URL but I cannot find anything similar for authors. So for instance I get this:

```
http://mysite.com/author/borekb
```

instead of

```
http://mysite.com/autor/borekb
```

which would be appropriate in my language. How to achieve that?

(And BTW, can "borekb" be replaced with something like "borek-bernard", i.e. full name slug instead of username?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the plugin [Edit Author Slug](http://brandonallen.org/wordpress/plugins/edit-author-slug/):

> This plugin allows an Admin to change the author slug (a.k.a. – nicename), without having to actually enter the database. You can also change the Author Base (the ‘/author/’ portion of the author URLs). Two new fields will be added to your Dashboard. The “Edit Author Slug” field can be found under Users > Your Profile or Users > Authors & Users (Users > Users in WP 3.0). The “Author Base” field can be found under Settings > Permalinks.

Comment: Thanks. It's a pity that this plugin doesn't auto-convert author's slug to `firstname-lastname` and one needs to do this manually but it's better than the default WordPress behavior.

Comment: Imagine a site where two authors have the same name (yes, I had this). One author would get the slug `firstname-lastname-2`. Sometimes it is better not to automate everything. :)

Comment: I would still consider `firstname-lastname-2` much better than `userxyz`, at least for my purposes. Maybe I'll write the plugin author.

Comment: It would be good to have an actual code solution posted to this rather than a link to this plugin which seems to be linked on all related answers.